# Powershell Quotation

Tags: powershell

Thanks to anyone reading this. I am having an issue with this syntax. Perhaps someone can help me figure this out. The issue is with the space in C:\Program Files

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process powershell -Credential domain\differentUserName -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Sync\Console.exe" -verb runas}'"
```

Comment: If you are running this from PowerShell, you at least need to escape the inner double quotes like this `""`

Comment: If you're running this from cmd.exe, you should escape the nested double-quotes with backward slashes. e.g. `powershell.exe -command "Start-Process powershell -Credential domain\differentUserName -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command \"Start-Process \"C:\Program Files\Sync\Console.exe\"\" -verb runas'"`. Although, I'd suspect that `-verb runas`, should not be double nested, just single nested, more like: `powershell.exe -command "Start-Process powershell -Credential domain\differentUserName -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command \"Start-Process \"C:\Program Files\Sync\Console.exe\"\"' -verb runas"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up cheating and do this. If anyone can think of another way, I'll love to hear it but this solves the problem on hand at the moment.

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process powershell -Credential domain\differentUserName -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process "C:\Progra~1\Sync\Console.exe" -verb runas}'"
```